# conditional phrases

Tags: conditionals

I am confused regarding conditional. I know, for example, if I say:

> If he had not insulted me, I wouldn't have slapped him.

this means in reality, he insulted me and I slapped him,  but if I am talking about this incident with my friend and my friend says:

> You shouldn't have slapped him

and then I ask my friend:

> If he had insulted you, what would you have done?

in this situation if my friend says:

> If he had insulted me, I wouldn't have slapped him

I know this mean in reality he didn't insult my friend, and this is confusing part. When my friend says *"I wouldn't have slapped him"* in the above context, does this mean in reality my friend slapped him or not?

Comment: You're tying yourself up in knots here trying to write about complex hypothetical scenarios in a foreign language (I assume that's why you're inconsistent in where you write negating ***not, n't***). Obviously you just *asked* your friend what he would do *in an imaginary situation that never actually occurred*. So in "reality" your friend didn't do anything at all. But English does allow such constructions as *In that hypothetical situation, I wouldn't have slapped him [**even if / unless**] he had slapped me*. Which says nothing about what I *really* did, just what I *would* have done.

Comment: I wonder if the experience of the poster shows that maybe this should be on English Language Learner site?

Comment: [English Language Learner site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: While no native speaker would have any difficulty in understanding what is going in the OP's sentences, I do think there is an interesting question being raised here. The first counterfactual (*If he had not insulted me, I wouldn't have slapped him*) conveys what some call **dual meaning** (see e.g. [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4959139/)): it expresses 'a supposition while implying the factual state of affairs'. However,

Comment: the second counterfactual (*If he had insulted me, I wouldn't have slapped him*) does not convey dual meaning—it does not imply the factual state of affairs. And I think it is an interesting question **why** it is, precisely, that the first counterfactual conveys dual meaning, but the second one does not.

Comment: For example, you might think it is because the first counterfactual has a negative protasis (*he **had not** insulted me*) while the second has a positive one (*he **had** insulted me*). However, this cannot be the full story. The following is an example of a counterfactual with dual meaning **and** a positive protasis: *If Tom had studied hard, he would have passed the test* (implies *Tom has not studied hard and, as a consequence, he failed*). It is clear that there are some **pragmatic** considerations at work here, and it would be nice if one could spell those out.

Comment: @Araucaria Any thoughts about the above? I seem to remember you mentioning having an interest in pragmatics?

Comment: In this case, the truth of your friend slapping him is not really a linguistic issue. While it is possible to read the situation as  your friend being annoyed at not being insulted and slapping him for being polite, the reality of it is an historic issue. If you are talking about a hypothetical situation then no, she didn't slap him. If you are asking about a real event, asking why she slapped him when he was being so polite, then yes, she slapped him. This can only be determined by look at the real-world context, not divined from the words in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Both your examples have exactly the same structure: first, you describe a hypothetical situation (something that did **not** happen); then you describe the expected result of that situation.

---

In your first example:

> If he had not insulted me, I wouldn't have slapped him.

the **condition** is:

> he had not insulted me

(this is not true - what actually happened is that he **did** insult me), and the expected **result** is:

> I wouldn't have slapped him.

---

In your second example:

> If he had insulted me, I wouldn't have slapped him.

the **condition** is:

> he had insulted me

(this is not true - what actually happened is that he **did not** insult me), and the expected **result** is:

> I wouldn't have slapped him.

Comment: That's not quite the end of the story, though; besides structure (and sheer logic), there are also **pragmatic** considerations, and it is this pragmatic aspect that the OP is really getting at. **Pragmatically,** *If he had not insulted me, I wouldn't have slapped him* additionally implies that *he* did, in fact, insult the speaker, and that the speaker did, in fact, slap him.

Comment: If the same reasoning were applicable to all sentences of the same structure, then the second sentence, *If he had insulted me, I wouldn't have slapped him*, would have pragmatically implied that *he* didn't in fact insult the second speaker **and** that the second speaker **did** in fact slap him. But the second sentence, in the present context, carries no such pragmatic implication. And it is an interesting question why that is, exactly.

Comment: Some people might describe the situation as follows: the first counterfactual conveys **dual meaning**: it expresses 'a supposition while implying the factual state of affairs' (see e.g. [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4959139/)). But the second counterfactual does not convey dual meaning—it does not imply the factual state of affairs.

Comment: @linguisticturn I am afraid I don't follow your logic at all. Perhaps it would be better to post your own answer, instead of the numerous comments both here and to the question.

Comment: Point taken—except that I don't really have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[would](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/would)

> used to express an intention or plan after a verb in a past tense

[not](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/not)

> used to make a word or group of words negative, or to give a word or words an opposite meaning

`I wouldn't have slapped him` in the above context means they had no intention of slapping him for the hypothetical insult if it had come.

Comment: Please help me out.Am I right? in my first sentence insult occured and I slapped him.But in my second sentence in the above context insult didn't occur and my friend didn't slap him.

Comment: `If he had not insulted me,I wouldn't have slapped him.`->insult occurred and you slapped him. `If he had insulted me,I wouldn't have slapped him`->insult still occurred but you didn't slap him

Comment: I understand the explanation of first sentence.But i think second sentence means insult didn't occur and I didn't slap

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a question that can best be approached with a little help from logic definitions. I'm no philosopher, so please forgive this somewhat bumbling attempt.

In logic, the idea `if A, then B` is called implication. But there are many ways of understanding this relationship. From a nice little [introduction](https://philosophy.lander.edu/logic/conditional.html) from lander.edu here are 4 ways to think about "If ... then ..." statements:

> 1. **Logical**:  E. g., "If all philosophers are thinkers and John is a
>      philosopher, then John is a thinker."
> 2. **Definitional**:  E. g., "If Carol is anemic, then Carol has a low
>          concentration of erythrocytes in her blood."
> 3. **Causal**:  E. g., "If you strike the match, it will light."
> 4. **Decisional**: E. g., "If you donate to educational television, then
>      the company you work for will match the amount."

So the first example:

> If he had not insulted me, [then] I wouldn't have slapped him.

is a **causal** implication. A *caused* B to happen.

Your final example:

> If he had insulted me, [then] I wouldn't have slapped him

is a **decisional** implication. B is *decided on* when A happens.

The second "if ... then ..." statement:

> If he had insulted you, [then] what would you have done?

is outside of any of these groups. It is an entirely hypothetical question, rather than a statement. It asks what would happen should A occur.

So with these definitions in mind, let's look at why the first conditional statement implies that the action already took place. Let's remove a few of the particulars, and look more generic cases.

`If A had not happened, then I would not have done B` - this is a statement of cause and effect. The hypothetical part of this statement (the "if" statement) is that A did **not** take place, which then implies that A *did* happen, and so B followed.

`If A had happened, then I would not do B` - the hypothetical part of this question is that A will occur. This statement then defines what would follow should A take place.